# отсутствует оператор ">>"соответствующий этим операндам (vector, cin)

Tags: c++, vector, перегрузка-операторов

Простой пример, а где ошибка, понять начинающему в плюсах сложно...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> a;
    cin >> a; \\отсутствует оператор ">>"соответствующий этим операндам
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вам же компилятор все подробно расписал. Это вы в первую очередь должны нам сначала объяснить почему вы ожидаете, что этот код будет работать. Чем вы руководствовались, когда писали этот код?

Comment: @AnT справедливости ради, текст ошибки очень топорный, его бы не понял даже я, хотя я C++ знаю

Comment: согласен, для начинающего это просто чудовищная подножка. спасибо за понимание

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Читать сразу в вектор нельзя.

```
int a;
cin >> a;
```

Так - пожалуйста, а для вектора - надо оператор самому переписывать, но, думаю, вам нужно просто в цикле читать целочисленные значения и добавлять в вектор с помощью `.push_back()`.

Можно, конечно, и другими способами, но как начинающему, это будет проще всего.

Что-то типа

```
int N;
cin >> N;  // Сколько чисел читать
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    int k;
    cin >> k;
    a.push_back(k);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

эта ошибка возникла из-за того, что оператор >> не перегружен для вектора. 
Что такое перегрузка операторов и зачем оно вобще существует почитайте, например, [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Если в двух словах, то это работает аналогично перегрузке функций (если знаете что это такое). Только в роли функции в вашем случаем выступает оператор `>>` а сигнатура и переопределение, для вашего случая должны будут выглядеть так.

```
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& in, std::vector<int>& a)
{
    int v;
    in >> v;
    a.push_back(v);
    return in;
}
```

Компилятору нужно таким вот образом объяснить как считывать значения в вектор с помощью оператора `>>`.